# Orthogonal projection and norm

Tags: linear-algebra

For $Q=Q^T>0$  and $R=R^T$ and $A$ Full Row Rank,

What can we say about $R$ if the norm $\left\Vert \left(I-A^{-R}A\right)R\right\Vert _{Q}^{2}=\left(I-A^{-R}A\right)RQ\left(I-A^{-R}A\right)R=0$ ?

Here $A^{-R}=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$

Comment: Does "$Q>0$" mean $Q$ is positive definite? Is the output of this norm *matrices*? The middle expression looks like a matrix, not a number. Is the statement missing something?

Answer (score 0):

$\|(I-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A)R\|_Q=0$ means that $(I-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A)R=0$ independently of $Q$. The matrix $P=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ is the orthogonal projector to the row space of $A$ and $(I-P)R=0$ means that $R=PR$, that is, the columns of $R$ lie in the subspace spanned by the rows of $A$ (as well as its rows due to the symmetry of $R$).

By the way, in the identity you compare norm (a number) with a matrix. How exactly do you define the $Q$-norm of the matrix? One possible way is to set
$$
\|X\|_Q = \max_{v\neq 0}\frac{\|Xv\|_Q}{\|v\|_Q} = \|Q^{1/2}XQ^{-1/2}\|_2,
$$
or to use a dual vector norm $\|\cdot\|_{Q^{-1}}$ in either range or domain of $X$ to get either $\|X\|_Q=\|Q^{-1/2}XQ^{-1/2}\|_2$ or $\|X\|_Q=\|Q^{1/2}XQ^{1/2}\|_2$.

In any case, norm of something is zero iff something is zero independently of the norm (of course in finite dimensional spaces).